# Maximum boundary of matrix differential equation solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the following differential equation $$\dot x(t)=-A(t)x+B(t)$$ where $A(t)$ is a positive definite matrix (uniformly in $t$) and $B(t)$ is a bounded vector ($||B(t)||\le \bar B$) $\forall t\ge 0$. In this case I am pretty sure that $x(t) \le max\{||x(0)||,\lambda_{min}(A)\bar B\}$. Is that right?

What if $A(t)$ is a positive semi-definite matrix? Is $x(t)$ bounded in that case?

Comment: Is $A$ assumed to be **uniformly** positive definite in $t$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp yes